# From $D = \{z : |z − 1| < √ 2, |z + 1| < √ 2\}$ onto the open first quadrant under a conformal mapping

Tags: complex-analysis, transformation

> Find a conformal mapping of the region $D = \{z : |z − 1| <
> √
> 2, |z + 1| <
> √
> 2\}$ onto the
>   open first quadrant.

We first note that the two circles intersect at right angles.

By conformality, the images
will intersect at right angles.

So if we find a LFT which maps $(−i, i, √
2−1) → (0,∞, 1),$
we should have the required mapping.

The mapping will have the form $f(z) = α
\frac{z+i}{
z−i}
.$

Let $β =
√
2 − 1$ and $f(β) = α
\frac{β+i}{
β−i }= 1,$ so $α =
\frac{β−i}{β+i}$ 
 and the mapping is $f(z) =\frac{ β−i}{
β+i}
\frac{z+i}{
z−i}.$

This exercise and answer is from here https://www.mathstat.dal.ca/~iron/math5020/hw2sol-15.pdf Exercise 6. a)

Question:

Why finding a LFT  which maps $(−i, i, √
2−1) → (0,∞, 1),$
would be enough for the required mapping ?

Is the order of the points important? Why are the points $(0,\infty,1)$ taken in that order? I recall that I did find some transformations and the order was: $\to(1,0,\infty)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Why finding a LFT which maps $(−i,i,\sqrt2−1)→(0,\infty,1)$, would be enough for the required mapping?"

An LFT is conformal in any case, so it is enough to verify the boundary of the image $I$.

The LFT maps a circle/line to a circle/line.
So, the images of the circles $|z-1|=\sqrt2$ and $|z+1|=\sqrt2$ are circles or lines. 
The two corners $\pm i$ are mapped to $0$ and $\infty$, so those boundary curves pass through $\infty$, indicating that they are some straight lines passing through $0$.

The LFT preserves orientated angles; in particular, the right angle at $-i$ is mapped to a right angle at $0$; so the two boundary lines of $I$ are perpendicular. Therefore, $I$ is a right angled angle domain with vertex at $0$.

Finally, the boundary point $\sqrt2-1$ lies on the circle arc on right side of the first domain, and it is mapped to $1$, so $1$ lies on the lower leg of that angle domain. Tis fixes the direction for the right angle.

"Is the order of the points important? Why are the points $(0,\infty,1)$ taken in that order? I recall that I did find some transformations and the order was: $\to(1,0,\infty)$"

There are two questions here.

The first question is the orientation of the points. In case of such simple regions, a conformal map sends the oriented boundary of one region to the oriented boundary of the other region. So, the order of the 3 points around the boundary must be preserved. This accords to the argument principle: if you walk around $0$ along the boundary of the first region, your image should go $+1$ times around the image of $0$. So you cannot replace say $(0,\infty,1)$ by $(\infty,0,1)$.

The second question is about cyclic shifts of the points. In general, it is possible to replace $(0,\infty,1)$ by $(1,0,\infty)$ and obtain another conformal map, but the new map will not be  an LFT, because the angles at the boundary are not preserved: the right angle at $-i$ is mapped to a straight angle at $1$.

Comment: I have a question: $i$ is sent to $\infty$, though $\infty$ does not have a right angle, why?

Comment: Could you also explain this with more detail: if you walk around $0$ along the boundary of the first region, your image should go $+1$ times around the image of $0.$ ?

Comment: Take a point form the angle domain, say let $a=1+i$. The conformal map attains $a$ exactly once with multiplicity $1$. The geometric interpretation of the argument principle is that the winding number of the boundary, with respect to $a$, is $+1$.

Comment: The angle domain has a right angle at infinity.

Answer (score 1):

> Is the order of the points important?

No. I'll explain in a second.

> Why are the points (0,∞,1) taken in that order?

The order of (0,∞,1) is dependent (in this case) on the order of (−i,i,√2−1). However, that order is indeed arbitrary. The notation that the solution uses can be a bit confusing I admit. It is simply telling you that the LFT should map: $-i \rightarrow 0$, $i \rightarrow \infty$, and $\sqrt{2}-1 \rightarrow 1$. The caveat to this is that this mapping is not strict either. For instance, the following would still be a valid mapping: $i \rightarrow 0$, $-i \rightarrow \infty$, and $-\sqrt{2}+1 \rightarrow 1$ However this different mapping would require a different transformation.. do you see why?

> Why finding a LFT which maps (−i,i,√2−1)→(0,∞,1), would be enough for the required mapping?

I suspect you are new to conformal mappings? Totally fine! The mappings to $0$ and $\infty$ should be relatively self-explanatory because we are trying to map to all of the first quadrant. Mapping to $1$ might be a little less intuitive, but we are really just mapping to a finite, non-zero point. Doesn't have to be $1$ but it makes the derivation simple! This allows us (and if you don't believe me plug in a couple other points and check) to map to all of the first quadrant using the transformation that the proof goes on to derive.

Answer (score 0):

> Why finding a LFT which maps (−i,i,√2−1)→(0,∞,1), would be enough for the required mapping ?

Because you **only** need to take 3 boundary points (from the domain region) and to see the image of them in the boundary under LFT. And this would be **enough** to determine the complete transformation.

> Is the order of the points important?

Yes.

> Why are the points (0,∞,1) taken in that order?

This is well addressed in user141614's answer.

Comment: This answer is wrong. 3 boundary points determine the conformal map. But what guarantees that the conformal map will be an LFT?